# do I need to install packages every time in python virtual environment?

Tags: python

when I activate my virtual environment and install packages that I need, when I close the command prompt or turn off the computer do I need to install packages again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to install it again if you restart your machine.

You need to reinstall again only it you destroy your virtual image and recreate it. If your have such scenario 
I will suggest to use configure tools like Chef which can automated to install all your setups once you recreate your image.

Comment: By destroying, you mean completely deleting the folder?

Comment: Destroying is generic term I used with VM. Destroying VM depends on VM implementation you are using Eg vagrant which does not destroy VM even if you delete it's state folder and keeps process running.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to re-install packages each time but you'll need to re-active the environment when you open a new prompt or turn your computer back on.

The Python Virtual Environment [documentation](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) covers how to activate and de-activate virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) the answer is No. The packages you have installed in a specific venv are persisted to disk.

Comment: Thanks!! I understand now.